# Determining CDF and PDF of a function on x

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I am trying to learn probability and have gotten to the points of transformations. I am now quite confused. While I understand what CDF and PDF are, I have no idea why changing the value of X to a function on X should drastically alter these, or how I should go about determining them. This is the problem statement I'm trying to figure out:

X is a continuous random variable.  Find the CDF and PDF of $Y=X^2$ in the expression of CDF FX of X and PDF fX of X.

How do I proceed here, especially since no actual function is given and no distribution specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extreme example of why composing a function with a random variable alters the distribution.
Consider the **uniform** random variable $X\sim U\{-1,1\}$.
That is, $\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1/2$.
Now, let $f$ be a function which maps everything to zero.
That is, $f(x)=0$.
Note that $\mathbb{P}(f(X)=0)=1$, yielding a **point mass** distribution.

---

If $X$ is a continuous random variable,
$$
\Phi_{X}(x)\equiv\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi_{X}(x)dx
$$
where $\Phi_{X}$ and $\varphi_{X}$ are the CDF and PDF of $X$.
The CDF of $Y\equiv X^{2}$ is given by
\begin{multline*}
\Phi_{Y}(y)\equiv\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X^{2}\leq y)
=\mathbb{P}(\left|X\right|\leq\sqrt{y})
=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq\sqrt{y})\\
=\mathbb{P}(X\leq\sqrt{y})-\mathbb{P}(X\leq-\sqrt{y})
=\Phi_{X}(\sqrt{y})-\Phi_{X}(-\sqrt{y})
\end{multline*}
To get the PDF from the CDF, just differentiate:
$$
\varphi_{Y}(y)=\Phi_{Y}^{\prime}(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left(\varphi_{X}(\sqrt{y})+\varphi_{X}(-\sqrt{y})\right).
$$
Since $\varphi_X$ was not specified, this is as far as you can simplify.

Comment: The formula you use for the CDF seems to be the same as the formula used to calculate expectation. Are these the same thing?

Comment: They are not the same thing. The expression for the expectation is $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \varphi_X(x) dx$. You should try to understand the motivation behind this and other expressions. It might help to consider the discrete case separately to do so.

Comment: What would happen if x were specified as a standard normal distribution?

Comment: You would plug in $\varphi_X(x) = \exp(-x^2/2) / \sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books: simplified my answer a bit.